# Bind mouse click on key including mouseclick hold function

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde

For health reasons, i mapped the mouse buttons on keys on keypad. This helps me, but I have solved the bindings via xdotool in KDE Custom shortcuts. With e.g. `xdotool click 1` you can simulate simple mouse clicks, but I would also like to drag a window when the mouse button is permanently pressed. Under windows this was possible with AutoHotKey. Is there an option to set this up in linux as well? I use Kubuntu 20.04 and KDE 5.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but it seems that keyboard shortcuts to call `xdotool mousedown 1` and `xdotool mouseup 1` could be set to provide more control over the mouse button than just clicking it. With this arrangement, the mousedown key would be hit to press the mouse button and keep it down, followed by mouse movement operations as needed. After that, the mouseup key would be hit to release the mouse button.